# Why can't the Beta distribution allow complex parameters?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The pdf of the Beta distribution is given by

$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}f(x;\alpha ,\beta )={\frac {x^{\alpha -1}(1-x)^{\beta -1}}{\displaystyle \int _{0}^{1}u^{\alpha -1}(1-u)^{\beta -1}\,du}}\end{aligned}}}$$

Where in the denominator as a normalization factor we have a Beta function and $\alpha, \beta> 0$.

Since the Beta function can be defined even for complex parameters $\alpha, \ \beta$ (with $Real(\alpha)>0$ and $Real(\beta)> 0$) I was wondering why we can't define the pdf of a Beta distribution for complex parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: One conventionally expects probabilities to be real numbers.

Comment: and similarly densities should be non-negative real numbers